# Why Paul does not use the word disciple to describe Christians?

Tags: pauline-epistles

I am surprised and don't understand why Paul does not use the word disciple but rather saint, brother or believer despite Jesus commanding to make disciples of all nations.

Comment: (a) why is this surprising? (b) does it really matter?

Jesus commands to "make disciples of all the nations", but I don't see how that's a mandate to use the word "disciple".

Comment: Also, "disciple" could be confusing to the Jews, who undoubtedly considered themselves disciples already.  But saying "believer" or "saint" would have been a word only referred to by those who "followed the Way" (because they weren't called "Christians" until Antioch; they were simply "believers")

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange, thanks for contributing! Be sure to take our [site tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about us. [We're a little different from other sites.](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/803/423)

Comment: I've flagged this question to be closed as it is primarily opinion-based and does not begin from the text. Please see the site tour and help centre for more info.

Comment: The word *disciple(s)* occurs nowhere else in the entire New Testament, except for the Four Gospels and Acts, so its absence is not restricted to Paul.

Comment: On the other hand, the word *apostle(s)* appears less than ten times in the Four Gospels ( compared to the 240 mentions of *disciple(s)* ), thirty times in Acts ( same for *disciple(s)* ), and forty-four times in the rest of the New Testament, of which only seven are outside of the Pauline corpus. I assume the explanation for this lies in the fact that, following His resurrection, described near the end of each Gospel, Christ **sent** His disciples (to preach the Gospel and baptize believers), thus effectively turning them into *apostles*.